# What is the difference between a lower bound and an upper bound in an Interval Graph $G(I)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

As I know that the maximal size of an independent set $IS$ of an interval Graph $G$ is a lower bound.

Now what is exactly the upper bound, and when they might be equivalent to each other.
are there any differences between them ?
Could someone explain that on the Graph here.

[image]

Example:
suppose you have a camera and you want to take a minimum number of pictures to the maximum number of people, and suppose each 1 hour comes n of persons, and after 1 hour comes another n persons and so on, so in this situation you have to take 1 photo every hour for n person because there is no possibility to take one picture for all $persons$  *who come in different times*  because they come after the other leave,

Similarly , suppose some of persons n come and stay till the other n comes so in this case we can capture only one image for (n and n) achieving 1 picture with maximum number of persons/

So what is the upper and lower bound of number of taking pictures ?

Comment: I'm probably just missing something obvious, but what do you mean when you say a "maximal independent set is a lower bound"? A lower bound *for what*?

Comment: @Casteels it is updated